# How to assign read/write permission to services in Android

Tags: android, fopen, stagefright, hal

I have put file dump logic inside following file in Android.
`frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp`

And to access this, i have made android application.
Now, my issue is when my logic gets called inside OMXCodec.cpp it gives `file open error in fopen() error:13`.

I am opening file in `"/mnt/test"` for writing in `w+` mode.

What can be reason behind that?

From my apk i am able to create file at same place("/mnt/test").

Comment: and you don't know what error number 13 is?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare these permissions in android Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

hope it helps

Comment: I have already checked with this, as mentioned in question i am able to make file through apk. But not working in HAL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In lollipop on wards Android has restricted all file open by SELinux. You need to give permission for SELinux. 
You can use command on adb shell:  **adb shell su -c setenforce 0** But This command you have to run after everytime device restart, as after reboot it will go to enforcement mode and again you won't be able to fopen.